# simplified acceleration and max speed calculations for a game?

Tags: modeling, simulation

Are there any simplified formulas that could be used to generate plausible airplane, spaceplane/SSTO, and spacecraft performance specs for a game given some basic vehicle and contextual attributes? By plausible, I mean within 25% of the value a full analysis might achieve. For example, could I roughly determine maximum acceleration and top speed from the following attributes:

```
VEHICLE
thrust (in real units)
mass (in real units)
aerodynamics (any intuitive scale: e.g. 0.0 = horrible, 1.0 = ideal, Boeing 
747 set arbitrarily at 0.50)


CONTEXT
atmosphere (density? pressure? friction? How best to measure simply?)
gravity (real units)
angle of travel (0 = parallel to planet, 90 = perpendicular to planet)
```

Comment: Have you checked game physics engines? There are several tutorials and examples for this topic. Note that g and air density will change wrt range to a planet.

Comment: Gurkan, I looked at Kerbal Space Program, but I'm not certain I want to design and build the crafts in that level of detail. From what I can tell, you need to actually test fly the design to know how it performs. I was hoping for some quick rules of thumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum acceleration can be calculated simply by comparing your vehicle's mass and thrust values:

$$F=m*a$$
$$acceleration = \frac{thrust}{mass}$$

The terminal velocity can be estimated by balancing your thrust values and the drag equation. When drag balances thrust, you cannot travel any faster

$$F_D=\frac{1}{2}\rho u^2C_DA$$

$$terminal\ velocity=\sqrt{\frac{2*thrust}{air \ density* drag\ coefficient*frontal\ area}}$$

You have also included 'angle of travel' as a factor - this will affect the total driving force in the direction of travel, and consequently the terminal velocity. If you are flying vertically upwards, the force due to gravity ($F=mg$) must be subtracted from the trust. If you are flying downwards at an angle of $20°$, then the component in the direction of travel ($F=mg\sin(\theta)$) should be added to the thrust.

Comment: Jonathan, would maximum acceleration be affected by aerodynamics? Given equal thrust and mass, wouldn't a block accelerate more slowly than a needle because the block has to push more air out of the way?

Comment: @davideps - it would not affect the *maximum* acceleration, since this occurs when the object first starts to move, and so there is no drag, because it's not moving! You're correct that the extent to which the vehicle is able to sustain its initial acceleration will be reduced as a function of the drag coefficient. For the purpose of this game, perhaps you could pick a fixed speed at which the acceleration is ranked (e.g. $100m/s$) and use resultant force when horizontal, rather than simply 'thrust' to calculate the acceleration? This would give a lower value for less aerodynamic shapes.

Comment: Can you define the terms in the FD = 1/2puCDA equation? is "A" the same as "a" in F = m * a? What is the appropriate measure for air density, drag, and frontal area if thrust is measured in newtons?

Comment: That's the standard Drag Equation - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation 'A' (note upper case) in this equation is 'frontal area', and not the same as 'a' (note lower case) which is acceleration. See the Wiki for full definitions. You can use whatever units you choose, as long as you're consistent!